# Get data from array in response in Swift

Tags: json, swift

i'm hitting an API and response is shown like this,

```
 "responseBody": {
    "data": [
        "{\"AED_USD\":0.272255,\"USD_AED\":3.67305}"
    ]
}
```

I'm confuse that how i can take out value of AED_USD and USD_AED from this array data. I have try to take all of the response in array and try to get value from index base but isn't working. How i can get the value? My code is this,

```
 let params = ["sourceCurrency":self.accountFromTxt.text!,
                  "targetCurrency":self.accountToTxt.text!] as [String : AnyObject]

    print(params)

    APIService.ExchangePrice(showActivityIndicator: true, parameters: params) { (responseObject) in
        if (responseObject?.status)!
        {
            self.print(responseObject?.data)

            self.exchangeRateArray.removeAll()

            if let usersDataArray = responseObject?.data as? [[String : Any]] {
                for userData in usersDataArray {
                    self.exchangeRateArray.append(ExchangeRateCurrency(JSON:userData)!)
                }

                if usersDataArray.count == 0
                {
                    //Empty Message
                    self.view.showEmptyScreenMessage(text: EmptyScreenMessages.transactionDetailMessage)
                }

                self.print(self.exchangeRateArray.count,self.exchangeRateArray[0])
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Utilities.showBar(text: responseObject?.errorObject?.message)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of `responseObject.data `? What is the type of `exchangeRateArray`? What is `ExchangeRateCurrency`? Basically `data` contains an array of **strings**. Each string is a JSON string representing a dictionary.

Comment: Seems to be JSON Stringified within JSON.

Comment: responseObject?.data is this "{\"AED_USD\":0.272255,\"USD_AED\":3.67305}"
and exchangeRateArray is the array i'm trying to store the response. @vadian

Comment: How i can get values out of it? @Larme

Comment: If `responseObject?.data` is "{\"AED_USD\":0.272255,\"USD_AED\":3.67305}" then it's clearly not an array.

Comment: So, how i can get value out? @vadian

Comment: Convert the string to `Data` and deserialize it with `JSONSerialization` to a dictionary

Comment: I have tried bottom code by not working fine. @vadian

Comment: Once again show the printed output of `print(responseObject?.data)` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in string form, change string to JSON NSdictonary.
try to convert like this

```
let str = "{\"AED_USD\":0.272257,\"USD_AED\":3.673001}"
        if let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
```

// In your code.

```
 let params = ["sourceCurrency":self.accountFromTxt.text!,
                      "targetCurrency":self.accountToTxt.text!] as [String : AnyObject]

        print(params)

        APIService.ExchangePrice(showActivityIndicator: true, parameters: params) { (responseObject) in
            if (responseObject?.status)!
            {
                self.print(responseObject?.data)

                self.exchangeRateArray.removeAll()

                if let usersDataArray = responseObject?.data as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for userData in usersDataArray {
                     print(userData)
 // if you get string from userData
            if let data = userData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print("Something went wrong")
                }
            }
                    }

                    if usersDataArray.count == 0
                    {
                        //Empty Message
                        self.view.showEmptyScreenMessage(text: EmptyScreenMessages.transactionDetailMessage)
                    }

                    //self.print(self.exchangeRateArray.count,self.exchangeRateArray[0])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Utilities.showBar(text: responseObject?.errorObject?.message)
            }
        }
```

Comment: this code is just printing ("[\"{\"AED_USD\":0.272257,\"USD_AED\":3.673001}\"]"). I want values out of it. @Sukhwinder Singh

Comment: replace data with """, it will be remove your comas and then remove slash(\) @Hamza

Comment: i didn't get can u explain more. @Sukhwinder Singh

Comment: It is showing nil in print(json). @Sukhwinder Singh

Comment: will you print(userData) and send me?, if you get "{\"AED_USD\":0.272257,\"USD_AED\":3.673001}" this from userData, then add my answer into the loop. you will get perfect dictionary. @Hamza

Comment: As from your previous code,
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                self.print(jsonString)
                let removeSlash = jsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                self.print(removeSlash)
It shows me this, Optional("[\"{\"AED_USD\":0.272258,\"USD_AED\":3.67298}\"]") . @Sukhwinder Singh

Comment: Which loop i should add it? .@Sukhwinder Singh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200235/discussion-between-sukhwinder-singh-and-hamza).

Comment: It is showing me error on this line,
if let data = userData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
Error is Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'data' . @Sukhwinder Singh